# DevExpress Grid not display

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress

I am working with `Grid` control of `DevExpress WPF` and got an issue. You guys please help me.

I have a `Grid` which bind data from `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` is working perfectly. I can query the data and push them to `View`. The issue is I can load the data but they don't display in `Grid` even I can CRUD them.

This is my [demo](http://screencast.com/t/C57hnmFsS3).

Here is my code:

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="ResItemGridControl"
                 ItemsSource="{
                 Binding ItemTypeList,
                 Mode=TwoWay,
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 AutoPopulateColumns="False">

    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ItemCode"
                        Header="Code"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemCode, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ItemName" 
                        Header="Name"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView Name="ResItemTableView" 
                       ShowGroupPanel="False"
                       MultiSelectMode="None" NavigationStyle="Row" 
                       FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the DisplayMemberBinding parameters. ItemsSource takes care of the binding for the entire grid and for each column FieldName selects the field from the database record or ObservableCollection item or whatever.

Comment: Thanks johndsamuels... but still not works and I think the DisplayMemberBinding doesn't matter... I already used in another DEvExpress Grid.